WiFi Option is missing altogether
I recently had switched to Ubuntu 22.04, because Windows was too heavy. It seems that my WiFi Drivers are missing, and I can't find an option for it. Attached is the picture for the Wifi. I tried to install all drivers with sudo ubuntu-drivers install and tried upgrading them with sudo apt upgrade. Nothing changed, except that my GPU drivers were updated. Can somebody help me with this? I don't know which company my Wifi card is.

Please attach output of this terminal command: lspci -nnk -d ::0280
